# When will 16.04 AMIs be available on the AWS MarketPlace?

Tags: 16.04, cloud, aws

Any idea when would 16.04 images be released to AWS MarketPlace?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 I would like to know the answer to this as well please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16.04 AMIs are now available on AWS!

Comment: Yes, they are now listed:  https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/

Comment: Do you have any idea when an "official AMI is released" (as such that it is listed in the quickstart of the launch instance wizard)?

Comment: Any follow up on this anyone?